# Android raw resource .txt show symbols

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I tried using raw resource folder in order to store a text file.
(instead of hard coding it ).
The text is in hebrew so it's RTL(I don't think it's the problem).
The problem is that instead of the text I have inside I get only symbols.(����.)

This is how I get the text inside the resource file

```
 InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(id);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferLength = 0;

    String name = getNameByID(id);
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(name,MODE_PRIVATE);

    try {
        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
            fos.write(buffer,0,bufferLength);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution...
Delete the files and put them agin.
If that fails,Try to paste data manually(CTRL+V).